# Sms Custom Activity analytics window

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom, sms, custom-activity, sendsmsactivity

I developed Custom Activity for sending SMS from Journey Builder. For the SMS analytics we created app inside AppExchange part of the Salesforce Marketing Cloud. There are tables and graphs with statistics around sent and delivered messages. You can choose by dropdown, for every version of stopped journey, how many sms are sent and delivered.

Now we would like to move this window to appear on the left side of the Journey but when the Journey is stopped. After the user clicks on the Custom Activity, but in the stopped Journey - we would like to see this window appear on the left side. The same behaviour like it is in the official SMS Activity for sending SMS from Salesforce Marketing Cloud.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To allow the user interface of your application to open in a stopped/running interaction, you need to set the property of userInferfacees.configurationSupportsReadOnlyMode to true in your config.json file.

Here's a snippet...

```
"userInterfaces": {
    "configInspector": {
        "size": “medium”,
        "hideHeader": true,
        "emptyIframe": false
    },
    "configurationSupportsReadOnlyMode": true
},
```

For your application to understand whether to show the read-only analytics view or configuration view, you'll need to either retain the state of the instance of your custom activity or you can inspect the "status" property of the interaction you get from the Postmonger requestedInteraction event.

Comment: Thanks a lot @Macca! We tried a snippet and configuration window now appeared on the left side inside stopped Journey. Now we will try to get analytics with info from customActivity.js.